# ran into build error with Tensorflow Android examples: tensorflow/core/kernels/split_v_op.cc

Tags: android, build, tensorflow

I cloned the Tensorflow Android example from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/, followed the steps at https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install-ubuntu.html to build it, but ran into problems with the following error:

> tensorflow/core/kernels/split_v_op.cc:172:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'tensorflow::SplitVOpCPU::Compute' requested here
>     explicit SplitVOpCPU(OpKernelConstruction* c) : Base(c) {}

The build command that I used is:

```
sudo bazel build --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone --local_resources 4096,4.0,1.0 -j 1 -c opt //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```

please share ideas to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is similar to the one posted at

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8641#issuecomment-288586320

The bazel builder does not work with latest NDK build that comes with Android Studio.

Need to use NDK r12b in the WORKSPACE file.

Code could be compiled, but still spilled out the warnings...